# Importing .css from another CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to import fonts from Google Fonts without having them in the directory and without having to import them in my .html file. Is there any way to reference a .css file from your main .css file?

Comment: There might be a reason you need to do this, but in case you didn't know, while this does help to consolidate your CSS, it is actually better performance wise to include Google Fonts directly from the CDN in your HTML file instead of including it in the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code at the top of your main .css file, and point the url to the file you want to import.

```
@import url("file.css");
```